# Real number raised to complex number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

My question could be silly , but imagine that we want to compute the following expression as; $y=3^i$;
I saw one is tried to write the same expression as: $y=(e^{ln3})^i=0.45+i 0.89$.
however , i was thinking to convert 3 into polar form and then raise it to power i; That is to say $3=3e^{i0}$.When you raise this number to power i, you end up to get again 3. Also you can write it as $3=3e^{i2\pi}$ in which when you raise it to power i , we would get $3^i=(3e^{i2\pi})^i=3e^{-2\pi}$.
So which one is actually true, because will result in diffrent outcome! Do i miss any point here?H

Comment: Do you ‘raise it to power yourself’? ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some solutions depending on which branch of the complex plane we are consider. In general the logarithm is not a function since it is defined as
$$ \ln(z) = \ln |z| + i \operatorname{arg}(z)$$
Here $\arg(z)$ is the argument of $z$ which is multivalued due to the periodicity of the argument.

Now if we compute what you wanted we have
$$ 3^i = e^{\ln(3^i)} = e^{i \ln(3)} = e^{i (\ln |3| + i \operatorname{arg}(3))} = e^{i (\ln|3|) + i 2 \pi n}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
So all the solutions are given by
$$ 3^i =e^{- 2 \pi n} e^{i \ln |3|}, \ n \in \mathbb{
Z}$$
However if we select a branch for the argument function, such as $$ \operatorname{arg}(3) = 0$$
Then the above becomes
$$ 3^i = e^{i \ln|3|}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your response; But still i did'nt  get why cant we directly convert the number in the form of $3=3e^{i0}$? Rather we have to write it in the form of ln function?

Comment: Because that is only partially true! Think about "how" you would go about doing this conversion. You would first write $3 = \exp(\ln(3)) = \exp(\ln|3| + i \operatorname{Arg}(3)), \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Again we are faced with the fact that the argument function is periodic with $2 \pi$ and hence we are left with $3 = \exp(\ln|3| + i 2 \pi n), \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which gives us the result $ 3 = e^{2 \pi n}$! Which is indeed true, a complex number may have its argument shifted by $2 \pi$ and we are still left with the same number.